# How can I automatically move photos from Google Plus to Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-plus

If I take a picture with my Samsung phone, the picture is automatically stored in Google Plus. Is it possible to move the photo to Google Drive automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with this App. I just happens to find this.
http://android.appstorm.net/how-to/synchronization/how-to-sync-photos-to-google-drive-via-foldersync/

I'm definitely looking forward for a plugins from google to do this directly without going through third party app :)

Comment: It's a nice app with a lot of functions. But still direct integration would be preferable.

Comment: @TonPlomp Yes, totally agree, but I did some googling, but coulnd't find it :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now: Enter a photo folder on G+.  Click on 'Add Photos' at the upper right.   Click on 'Google Drive' near top.  Appears you have to select individual photos - I don't see a way to do whole albums/folders.

Comment: This is moving photos from Drive to Plus and not automatically.

Comment: does this count against your Google Drive storage limit if the pictures are 2048x2048 or smaller?

Comment: Not helpful - this is the opposite of the question